# What is wrong in this code? I'm getting time limit exceeded error.

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main() {
    int test_case, count, i, j, check, count_1; char a[100005];
    scanf("%d", &test_case);
    while(test_case--) {
        scanf("%s", a);
        count=count_1=0;
        for(i=0;i<strlen(a);i++) {
            if(a[i]=='1') {
                count_1++;    
            }
        }
        for(i=0;i<strlen(a);i++) {
            if(a[i]=='1'&&a[i+1]!='1'&&a[i+1]!='\0') {
                count++;
                for(j=(i+1);j<strlen(a);j++) {
                    if(a[j]=='0') {
                        a[j]='1';
                        a[j-1]='0';
                        count++;
                    }
                    else {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if(i==(strlen(a)-1)) {
                check=0;
                for(j=(strlen(a)-1);j>=1;j--) {
                    if(a[j]=='1'&&a[j-1]=='1') {
                        check++;
                    }
                    else {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(check==(count_1-1)) {
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    i=0;
                }
            }
        }
        printf("%d\n", count);
    }
return 0;
}
```

[This is the question.](https://www.codechef.com/APRIL17/problems/ROWSOLD)

I have carried out a few dry runs and I'm getting the results. I'm not sure why I'm getting time limit exceeded error. The code is working for every test case except #2 (that is 1100001).

Please help me I'm stuck on this one for quite a while.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon.  Your question should be meaningful without the need to refer to an external site like CodeChef to find out what problem you are solving.  Please include the relevant information directly in your question.

Comment: Maybe an infinite loop somewhere?

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)....) & **use the debugger** `gdb`;  BTW your fix-my-code question is off-topic

Comment: Loops like `for(j=(i+1);j<strlen(a);j++) {` should be rewritten to avoid calculating the string length on each iteration.  Whether that really accounts for your problem is a separate discussion.

Comment: The point of CodeChef, SPOJ, Project Euler, etc, are to test **your** skills: not ours. If I could solve this problem, I would submit it directly to CodeChef, not to you. Quite often, the obvious solution will hit the time limit. The real question is to go further and find a slick algorithm.

Comment: You can add some `printf`s to locate the problem: http://ideone.com/6aGnba Your second and fourth loop create a endless loop.

Comment: Not that it is the timing problem, but not testing the return value from scanf() is always asking for trouble.

Comment: @mch : Thanks, i just needed to change i=0 to i=-1 to avoid infinite looping.

Comment: @Jeff Please create an answer instead of writing a comment with the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to change i=0 to i=-1 to avoid infinite looping.

Comment: I assume you mean the second `i = 0`

Comment: You should be able to accept your answer now, I believe, as more than 48 hours have elapsed.

Comment: Did avoiding infinite loops mean your code was faster than the limit even on long strings?  I wrote a quadratic algorithm that was too slow on the maximum, but looking at how it worked allowed me to see a linear algorithm that calculated the correct answer without ever modifying the input data or rescanning anything that had already been processed.  It achieved times of the order of 30 ms where the quadratic algorithm gave times of the order of 10 s (300 times as long) at size 9500.